# Implementing clustered coordianted timer (runs on one node only in Payara Micro Cluster) using IScheduledExecutorService

Tags: hazelcast, payara-micro

I am trying to achieve the following behavior for the clustered coordinated events:

1. timer (event) is executed only in one thread\JVM in the Payara Micro cluster;
2. in case node goes down - timer (event) will be executed on another node in the cluster.

From the [Payara Micro guide](https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/5.2021.1/documentation/payara-micro/persistent-ejb-timers.html):

> Persistent timers are NOT coordinated across a Payara Micro cluster.
> They are **always executed on an instance with the same name** that
> created the timers.

and

> If that instance goes down, the timer will be recreated on another
> instance with the same name once it joins the cluster. **Until that
> time, the timer becomes inactive**.

Seems persistent timers will not work as desired in Payara Micro cluster by definition.

As such I am trying to use [IScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.1/computing/scheduled-executor-service.html) from Hazelcast, what seems to be a perfect match.

Basically implementation with IScheduledExecutorService works well except the scenario when the new Payara Micro node is starting & joining cluster (the cluster where some events already scheduled using IScheduledExecutorService). During this time the following exceptions happen:

**Exception 1:** java.lang.RuntimeException: ConcurrentRuntime not initialized

```
[2021-02-15T23:00:31.870+0800] [] [INFO] [] [fish.payara.nucleus.cluster.PayaraCluster] [tid: _ThreadID=63 _ThreadName=hz.angry_yalow.event-5] [timeMillis: 1613401231870] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Data Grid Status 
Payara Data Grid State: DG Version: 4 DG Name: testClusterDev DG Size: 2
Instances: {
 DataGrid: testClusterDev Name: testNode0 Lite: false This: true UUID: 493b19ed-a58d-4508-b9ef-f5c58e05b859 Address: /10.41.0.7:6900
 DataGrid: testClusterDev Lite: false This: false UUID: f12342bf-a37e-452a-8c67-1d36dd4dbac7 Address: /10.41.0.7:6901
}]]

[2021-02-15T23:00:32.290+0800] [] [WARNING] [] [com.hazelcast.internal.partition.operation.MigrationRequestOperation] [tid: _ThreadID=160 _ThreadName=ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-6] [timeMillis: 1613401232290] [levelValue: 900] [[
  [10.41.0.7]:6900 [testClusterDev] [4.1] Failure while executing MigrationInfo{uuid=fc68e9ac-1081-4f9b-a70a-6fb0aae19016, partitionId=27, source=[10.41.0.7]:6900 - 493b19ed-a58d-4508-b9ef-f5c58e05b859, sourceCurrentReplicaIndex=0, sourceNewReplicaIndex=1, destination=[10.41.0.7]:6901 - f12342bf-a37e-452a-8c67-1d36dd4dbac7, destinationCurrentReplicaIndex=-1, destinationNewReplicaIndex=0, master=[10.41.0.7]:6900, initialPartitionVersion=1, partitionVersionIncrement=2, status=ACTIVE}
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: ConcurrentRuntime not initialized
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleException(SerializationUtil.java:103)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:292)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:567)
    at com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.ScheduledRunnableAdapter.readData(ScheduledRunnableAdapter.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:286)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:567)
    at com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.TaskDefinition.readData(TaskDefinition.java:144)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:286)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:567)
    at com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.ScheduledTaskDescriptor.readData(ScheduledTaskDescriptor.java:208)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:286)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:567)
    at com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.operations.ReplicationOperation.readInternal(ReplicationOperation.java:87)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.Operation.readData(Operation.java:750)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:286)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:567)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.partition.ReplicaFragmentMigrationState.readData(ReplicaFragmentMigrationState.java:97)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:286)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.ByteArrayObjectDataInput.readObject(ByteArrayObjectDataInput.java:567)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.partition.operation.MigrationOperation.readInternal(MigrationOperation.java:249)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.Operation.readData(Operation.java:750)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.readInternal(DataSerializableSerializer.java:160)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:106)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.DataSerializableSerializer.read(DataSerializableSerializer.java:51)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:205)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toObject(NodeEngineImpl.java:346)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:437)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:166)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:136)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.executeRun(OperationThread.java:123)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ConcurrentRuntime not initialized
    at org.glassfish.concurrent.runtime.ConcurrentRuntime.getRuntime(ConcurrentRuntime.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.concurrent.runtime.InvocationContext.readObject(InvocationContext.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2296)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2329)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2187)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:461)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:83)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.defaultserializers.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:76)
    at fish.payara.nucleus.hazelcast.PayaraHazelcastSerializer.read(PayaraHazelcastSerializer.java:84)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:44)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.readObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:286)
    ... 50 more
]]

[2021-02-15T23:00:32.304+0800] [] [WARNING] [] [com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.MigrationManager] [tid: _ThreadID=160 _ThreadName=ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-6] [timeMillis: 1613401232304] [levelValue: 900] [10.41.0.7]:6900 [testClusterDev] [4.1] Migration failed: MigrationInfo{uuid=fc68e9ac-1081-4f9b-a70a-6fb0aae19016, partitionId=27, source=[10.41.0.7]:6900 - 493b19ed-a58d-4508-b9ef-f5c58e05b859, sourceCurrentReplicaIndex=0, sourceNewReplicaIndex=1, destination=[10.41.0.7]:6901 - f12342bf-a37e-452a-8c67-1d36dd4dbac7, destinationCurrentReplicaIndex=-1, destinationNewReplicaIndex=0, master=[10.41.0.7]:6900, initialPartitionVersion=1, partitionVersionIncrement=2, status=ACTIVE}
```

This seems to happen because the new node is not fully initialized (as it is just starting). Looks like this exception is less critical comparing with the next one.

**Exception 2:** java.lang.NullPointerException: Failed to execute java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask

```
[2021-02-15T23:44:19.544+0800] [] [SEVERE] [] [com.hazelcast.spi.impl.executionservice.ExecutionService] [tid: _ThreadID=35 _ThreadName=hz.elated_murdock.scheduled.thread-] [timeMillis: 1613403859544] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  [10.4.0.7]:6901 [testClusterDev] [4.1] Failed to execute java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@55a27ce3
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.glassfish.concurrent.runtime.ContextSetupProviderImpl.isApplicationEnabled(ContextSetupProviderImpl.java:326)
        at org.glassfish.concurrent.runtime.ContextSetupProviderImpl.setup(ContextSetupProviderImpl.java:194)
        at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.internal.ContextProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ContextProxyInvocationHandler.java:94)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy154.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.ScheduledRunnableAdapter.call(ScheduledRunnableAdapter.java:56)
        at com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.TaskRunner.call(TaskRunner.java:78)
        at com.hazelcast.scheduledexecutor.impl.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:104)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.executionservice.impl.DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator$DelegateDecorator.run(DelegateAndSkipOnConcurrentExecutionDecorator.java:77)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.CachedExecutorServiceDelegate$Worker.run(CachedExecutorServiceDelegate.java:217)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
        at com.hazelcast.internal.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:102)
]]
```

This exception happens on the new node which is joining cluster. This doesn't happen always, probably Hazelcast is trying to execute event on the new node which is starting, and it fails becasue environment still not fully initialized. The issue that after two such failed attempts - event gets unloaded by Hazelcast.

---

Implementation insights:

Method which schedules event using IScheduledExecutorService (resides in application scoped bean in the main app WAR):

```java
@Resource
ContextService _ctxService;

public void sheduleClusteredEvent() {
    IScheduledExecutorService executorService = _instance.getScheduledExecutorService("default");
    ClusteredEvent ce = new ClusteredEvent(new DiagEvent(null, "TestEvent1"));
    Object ceProxy = _ctxService.createContextualProxy(ce, Runnable.class, Serializable.class);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate((Runnable) ceProxy, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

ClusteredEvent class (resides in a separate JAR and added to classpath via --addLibs param to the Payara Micro). It needs to somehow inform the main app about the event to be trigered, thus BeanManager.fireEvent() is used.

```java
public class ClusteredEvent implements Runnable, Serializable {
    private final DiagEvent _event;
    public ClusteredEvent(DiagEvent event) {
        _event = event;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // For sake of shortness - all check for nulls etc. were removed
        ((BeanManager) ic.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager")).fireEvent(_event);
    }
}
```

**So my questions:**

1. How to solve the mentioned above exceptions / issues?
2. Am I on the right direction in achieving coordinated clustred events behaviour in Payara Micro cluster? I would expect this to be a trivial task working out-of-the-box, but instead it requires some custom implementation as persistent timers do not work as desired. Is there any other more elegant way available with Payara Micro Cluster (>=v5.2021.1) of achiving coordinated clustred events behaviour?

Thank you so much in advance!

---

**Update 1:**

Just to recall that the main purpose of this exercise is to have coordinated timer (events) functionality available in the Payara Micro Cluster, thus suggestions on more elegant solutions are highly welcome.

Addressing questions/suggestions from the comments:

**Q1:**

> why do you need to create a contextual proxy for the even object?

**A1:** Indeed making the contextual proxy out of the plain `ClusteredEvent()` object - adds the main complexity here and causes listed above exceptions (meaning: scheduling `ClusteredEvent()` without making a contextual proxy out of it - works fine and doesn't cause exceptions, but there is a caveat).

The reason contextual proxy is used as I need to somehow trigger the main app running on Payara Micro from the un-managed thread launched by `IScheduledExecutorService`. So far I haven't found any other workable way of triggering any CDI/EJB bean in the main app from the un-managed thread. Only making it contextual - allows `ClusteredEvent.run()` to communicate with the main app via `BeanManger` for example.

Any suggestions on how to establish communication between un-managed thread and CDI/EJB beans running in separate app (and both running on the same Payara Micro instance) - are welcome.

**Q2:**

> You can for example wrap the ceProxy to a Runnable, that executes ceProxy.run() in a try catch block

**A2:** I have tried it and indeed it helps to handle the "Exception 2" mentioned above. I am posting implementation of the `ClusteredEventWrapper` class below, try/catch inside run() method handles "Exception 2".

**Q3:**

> The first exception comes from hazelcast trying to deserialize the
> proxy on the new instance, which fails because the proxy needs an
> initilaized environment to deserialize. To solve this, you would need
> to wrap the ceProxy object and customize the deserialization of the
> wrapper to wait until the ContextService is initilaized.

**A3:** Adding custom implementation for serialization/deserialization of `ClusteredEventWrapper` indeed allows to handle "Exception 1", but here I am still struggling on the best way of handling it. Postponing deserialization via `Thread.sleep()` - causes new (different) exceptions. Supressing of exceptions - need to check, but in that case I am afraid `ClusteredEventWrapper` will not be properly deserialized on the new (starting) node, as Hazelcast will consider sync was good and will not try to sync it again (I may be wrong - this I still need to check). As currently seems Hazelcast tries to sync several times util the "Exception 1" gone.

Implementation of the `ClusteredEventWrapper` which wraps `ClusteredEvent`:

```java
public class ClusteredEventWrapper implements Runnable, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5878537035999797427L;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ClusteredEventWrapper.class.getName());

    private final Runnable _clusteredEvent;

    public ClusteredEventWrapper(Runnable clusteredEvent) {
        _clusteredEvent = clusteredEvent;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            _clusteredEvent.run();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (e instanceof NullPointerException
                    && e.getStackTrace() != null && e.getStackTrace().length > 0
                    && "org.glassfish.concurrent.runtime.ContextSetupProviderImpl".equals(e.getStackTrace()[0].getClassName())
                    && "isApplicationEnabled".equals(e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName())) {
                // Means we got the "Exception 2" (posted above)
                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Skipping scheduled event execution on this node as this node is still being initialized...");
            } else {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error executing scheduled event", e);
            }
        }
    }


    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "1_WRITE_OBJECT...");
        out.defaultWriteObject();
    }


    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        LOG.log(Level.INFO, "2_READ_OBJECT...");
        int retry = 0;
        while (readObjectInner(in) != true && retry < 5) { // This doesn't work good, need to think of some other way on handling it
            retry++;
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, "2_READ_OBJECT: retry {0}", retry);
            try {
                // We need to wait 
                Thread.sleep(15000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean readObjectInner(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            in.defaultReadObject();
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (e instanceof RuntimeException && "ConcurrentRuntime not initialized".equals(e.getMessage())) {
                // This means node which is trying to desiarialize this objet is not ready yet
                return false;
            } else {
                // For all other exceptions - we throw error
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So now event scheduled in the following way:

```java
@Resource
ContextService _ctxService;

public void sheduleClusteredEvent() {
    IScheduledExecutorService executorService = _instance.getScheduledExecutorService("default");
    ClusteredEvent ce = new ClusteredEvent(new DiagEvent(null, "PersistentEvent1"));
    Object ceProxy = _ctxService.createContextualProxy(ce, Runnable.class, Serializable.class);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ClusteredEventWrapper((Runnable) ceProxy), 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Hi, why do you need to create a contextual proxy for the even object? What happens if you schedule the `ClusteredEvent` object instead? It looks like that the proxy is invoked on a new Payara Micro instance before the environment is initialized. This also means that the exception comes from the code that you pass to the executor so you can modify it. You can for example wrap the `ceProxy` to a Runnable, that executes `ceProxy.run()` in a try catch block and either return without error or retry after some delay.

Comment: The first exception comes from hazelcast trying to deserialize the proxy on the new instance, which fails because the proxy needs an initilaized environment to deserialize. To solve this, you would need to wrap the ceProxy object and customize the deserialization of the wrapper to wait until the ContextService is initilaized. If you create a sample project on github, we can work on it together to get it working.

Comment: Hi Ondro, thank you so much for responding to this post! Let me address your questions and suggestions:
Q1) "why do you need to create a contextual proxy for the even object": seems IScheduledExecutorService runs thread (`ClusteredEvent.run()`) in NOT-managed context. But I need to somehow notify main application about the scheduled event, for this I was using `BeanManager.fireEvent()` and respective method with `@Observes` argument (e.g.: `.processEvent(@Observes DiagEvent event)`).

Comment: Q1.continued) Because of the NOT-managed context in `ClusteredEvent.run()` - any JNDI-lookups (using `new InitialContext()` without and with properties) - always gave nothing. I was trying to pass BeanManager or InitialContext via Inversion of Control (e.g.: `new ClusteredEvent(beanManager, new DiagEvent(null, "TestEvent1"))`) - but nothing worked well. Only after wrapping `ClusteredEvent` into contextual proxy - `(BeanManager) ic.lookup("java:comp/BeanManager")` started to work properly. Here I am open for any other suggestions on how to notify the main app from the un-managed thread.

Comment: Q2) "You can for example wrap the ceProxy to a Runnable, that executes ceProxy.run() in a try catch block and either return without error or retry after some delay": will try shortly!
Q3) "To solve this, you would need to wrap the ceProxy object and customize the deserialization of the wrapper to wait until the ContextService is initilaized." Also sounds feasible will give a try shortly.
Q4) "If you create a sample project on github, we can work on it together to get it working." Sounds great – after trying all the mentioned above – will prepare a test project to solve this puzzle! :)

Comment: @OndroMih, I have posted an "Update 1" with updates I got so far. Any advices are highly welcome. Meanwhile I will also work on preparing simple app which reproduces the discussed scenario. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think that a better approach to this is to avoid wrapping your object into a contextual and instead register BeanManager into a global variable (singleton) at application startup. In `ClusteredEvent.run()` you would retrieve it from a static method, e.g. `Registry.getBeanManager()`. This method would have to wait until the application starts up and saves its BeanManager instance with `Registry.setBeanManager()`. For example, it can wait for a result from a CompletableFuture which would be completed when the application starts up.

Comment: Such approach doesn't need any context at all. The disadvantage is that it relies on a global static variable but that shouldn't be an issue as you normally don't redeploy applications with Payara Micro. You could also execute the `run()` method in an executor service to unblock the Hazelcast thread. Or maybe even better if you store a reference to the ManagedExecutorService instead of the BeanManager, execute the run method with that executor and just inject anything you need.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds very feasible and much more simpler in terms of implementation. Will work on this approach and provide feedback shortly!

Comment: Hi @AndrewG10i, do you have any results? Were you able to implement what you needed? I'm interested in whether we can add it together into the Payara Micro core project.

Comment: Hello @OndroMih, yep, I was able to implement it and was about to publish all the details shortly. But will do it now to avoid further delay with my feedback! Thank you for all your suggestions, it really helped me much! And I would love to contribute with this solution to Payara Micro Project!

Comment: Hi @OndroMih, just curious is any functionality like this (clustered timers) already available in Payara 6? ...I do not remember that I have seen anything about it in Release Notes. Thanks for clarifying! P.S. Updated my post below with minor adjustment on compatibility with Jakarta EE 10.

Comment: Hi, no, there’s not anything like this in Payara 6. I’m not involved with the Payara project anymore so if you need that feature, contact the Payara team. I now work at OmniFish company and I work on the Eclipse GlassFish project.

Comment: Hi Ondro, sad to hear that you are not with Payara anymore but glad to learn about OmniFish, as haven't heard about it before but now will keep eye on it. ;) As per the feature discussed in scope of this post - I still use the solution which was developed with your help in scope of this thread. Recently upgraded it (solution) to the Jakarta EE 10 (updated line of code posted above), and it keeps work absolutely fine and stable! :)

Answer (score 0):

Below I am posting implemented solution based on suggestions from **@OndroMih** in the comments:

Excerpt 1:

> ...a better approach to this is to avoid wrapping your object into a
> contextual and instead register `BeanManager` into a global variable
> (singleton) at application startup. In `ClusteredEvent.run()` you would
> retrieve it from a static method, e.g. `Registry.getBeanManager()`. This
> method would have to wait until the application starts up and saves
> its `BeanManager` instance with `Registry.setBeanManager()`

And this one:

Excerpt 2:

> Or maybe even better if you store a reference to the
> `ManagedExecutorService` instead of the `BeanManager`, execute the run
> method with that executor and just inject anything you need.

@OndroMih, please post them as reply - I will mark it as an accepted answer!

---

Before going into details of the implementation - few words on our application packaging: it consists of:

1. the main `war` file which is bundled into Payara Micro as Uber jar, so we do not redeploy application war, we start and stop the whole Payara Micro with the deployed war on it;
2. and tiny `jar` lib with few classes which are used mainly in Hazelcast and provided via `--addLibs` arg to Payara Micro Uber jar to avoid ClassNotFoundExceptions when Hazelcast syncs objects in DataGrid.

---

And now about the implementation which has given us the desired behavior for the clustered timer/events (see the 1st post):

I) Using `ManagedExecutorService` as per suggestion above indeed looks much more flexible as it allows to inject any desired object into clustered event, so I started with this approach. But due to some reason - I was not able to inject anything. Due to limited time I left this for investigation in future and switched to the next approach. I am also providing sample code for this case in the end of this post.

II) So I switched to the scenario with `BeanManager`.

1. I got the `Registry` signleton implemented as follows (all comments are removed in sake of shortness). This class resides in the tiny jar added via `--addLibs` arg to Payara Micro:

```java
public final class Registry {

    private ManagedExecutorService _executorService;

    private BeanManager _beanManager;

    private Registry() {
    }

    public ManagedExecutorService getExecutorService() {
        return _executorService;
    }

    public void setExecutorService(ManagedExecutorService executorService) {
        _executorService = executorService;
    }

    public BeanManager getBeanManager() {
        return _beanManager;
    }

    public void setBeanManager(BeanManager beanManager) {
        _beanManager = beanManager;
    }

    public static Registry getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder._instance;
    }

    private static class InstanceHolder {
        private static final Registry _instance = new Registry();
    }
}
```

2. In the main app war we already had an AppListener class which listens for the event when app is deployed, so we added `Registry` population logic into it:

```java
public class AppListener implements SystemEventListener {

    ...

    @Resource
    private ManagedExecutorService _managedExecutorService;

    @Resource
    private BeanManager _beanManager;

    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
        try {

            if (event instanceof PostConstructApplicationEvent) {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, ">> Application started");
                ...
                // Once app marked as started - populate global objects in the Registry
                Registry.getInstance().setExecutorService(_managedExecutorService);
                Registry.getInstance().setBeanManager(_beanManager);
            }
            
            ...
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, ">> Error processing event: " + event, e);
        }
    }
}
```

3. `ClusteredEvent` class which as scheduled via `IScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()` also resides in the tiny jar and has the following implementation:

```java
public final class ClusteredEvent implements NamedTask, Runnable, Serializable {

    ...

    private final MultiTenantEvent _event;

    public ClusteredEvent(MultiTenantEvent event) {
        if (event == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Event can not be null");
        }
        _event = event;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (Registry.getInstance().getBeanManager() == null) {
                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Skipping timer execution - application not initialized yet...");
                return;
            }
            Registry.getInstance().getBeanManager().fireEvent(_event);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error executing timer: " + _event, e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final String getName() {
        return _event.getName();
    }
}
```

4. And basically that is all. Scheduling is done using the following simple steps:

```java
@Resource(lookup = "payara/Hazelcast")
private HazelcastInstance _instance;

_instance.getScheduledExecutorService("default").scheduleAtFixedRate(new ClusteredEvent(event), initialDelaySec, invocationPeriodSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

All tests went good so far. I was worried that `Registry.getBeanManager()` getting 'spoiled' after some time due to some closed contexts somewhere (I am not sure about the nature of the BeanManager reference), but tests have shown that ref to BeanManager stays valid after 1 day, so hopefully it will work fine.

Another concern (even not a concern, but caveat to be considered) that there is no possibility to control on which node event is to be fired by `IScheduledExecutorService`, as such when event is triggered on the node which is not yet initialized (still starting) - the event gets skipped. But for our usage-scenario this is acceptable, so currently we can live with these considerations.

---

And getting back to the issue with usage of `ManagedExecutorService`: `ClusteredEvent` was implemented like provided below:

```java
public class ClusteredEvent implements Runnable, Serializable {

    private final MultiTenantEvent _event;

    public ClusteredEvent(MultiTenantEvent event) {
        _event = event;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, "TIMER THREAD NAME: {0}", Thread.currentThread().getName());

            if (Registry.getInstance().getExecutorService() == null) {
                LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "Skipping timer execution - application not initialized yet...");
                return;
            }
            
            Registry.getInstance().getExecutorService().submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Timer.Run() THREAD NAME: {0}", Thread.currentThread().getName());                    
                    String beanManagerJndiName = "java:comp/BeanManager";
                    try {
                        Context ic = new InitialContext();
                        BeanManager beanManager = (BeanManager) ic.lookup(beanManagerJndiName);
                        beanManager.fireEvent(_event);
                        return true;
                    } catch (NullPointerException | NamingException ex) {
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "ERROR: no BeanManager resource could be located by JNDI name: " + beanManagerJndiName, ex);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }).get();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error executing timer: " + _event, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Output was the following:

```
[2021-02-24 07:56:07] [INFO] [ua.appName.model.event.ClusteredEvent run]
 TIMER THREAD NAME: hz.competent_mccarthy.cached.thread-11

[2021-02-24 07:56:07] [INFO] [ua.appName.model.event.ClusteredEvent$1 call]
 Timer.Run() THREAD NAME: concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService-managedThreadFactory-Thread-1

[2021-02-24 07:56:07] [SEVERE] [ua.appName.model.event.ClusteredEvent$1 call]
 ERROR: no BeanManager resource could be located by JNDI name: java:comp/BeanManager
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/BeanManager' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation ]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at ua.appName.model.event.ClusteredEvent$1.call(ClusteredEvent.java:70)
    at ua.appName.model.event.ClusteredEvent$1.call(ClusteredEvent.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.internal.ManagedFutureTask.run(ManagedFutureTask.java:143)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThread.run(ManagedThreadFactoryImpl.java:250)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Invocation exception: Got null ComponentInvocation 
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.getComponentId(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:870)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:737)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:167)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:476)
    ... 11 more
```

So line `Timer.Run() THREAD NAME: concurrent/__defaultManagedExecutorService-managedThreadFactory-Thread-1` confirms that code runs already inside the managed thread but still I was not able to inject or lookup nothing. I left this investigation for future this time.

---

Once again, many thanks to **@OndroMih** for your suggestions on the implementation!

Thank you!

---

**Update as of 06-Jun-2023:**

---

So after I have performed migration of the app to Jakarta EE 10 on Payara 6 the following line has to be changed:
From:

```java
Registry.getInstance().getBeanManager().fireEvent(_event);
```

To:

```java
Registry.getInstance().getBeanManager().getEvent().fire(_event);
```

As per these deprecation notices: https://github.com/jakartaee/cdi/issues/472